# Facebook connect - Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to implement Facebook connect on my website to filling input fields.

But I can't get the email address or the last and first name despite my Facebook application ask me if it can access to the email address.

Here is my script:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '######', // App ID
            status     : true, // check login status
            xfbml      : true,
            cookie     : true,
            version    : 'v2.4' // Version
        });

    };

    function Login()
    {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if(response.authResponse) 
            {
                getUserInfo();
            }else{
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        },{scope: 'public_profile,email'});
    }

    function getUserInfo()
    {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {

                document.getElementById("name").value = response.name;
                document.getElementById("first_name").value = response.first_name;
                document.getElementById("last_name").value = response.last_name;
                document.getElementById("email").value = response.email;

            FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {

                    var str ="<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
                        str +="<input type='button' value='Logout' onclick='Logout();'/>";
                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=str;

            });
        });
    }

    function Logout()
    {
        FB.logout(function(){document.location.reload();});
    }

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_EN/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

</script>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly requests fields you need:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=email,...')
```

See chapter `Choosing Fields` in [Using the Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4) doc

You can also try your requests using `Graph API Explorer` in Tool & Support section in FB Developer site